# Identify an unknown type of hash

Tags: hash

I've come across an unknown type of hash value which looks like this:

`AAAAAATOM2KIII+kbR/Dqw3TLTw4PHsGPZft2c+b93rImFIuAQ==`

The corresponding hex string is:

`0000000004CE336288208FA46D1FC3AB0DD32D3C383C7B063D97EDD9CF9BF77AC898522E01`

I've tried to identify this string in [OnlineHashCrack](http://www.onlinehashcrack.com/hash_identification.php) but it seems I cannot get any hint. Can someone help me identify this hash type?

Some more examples:

Hash: `AAAAAASaQwt3IaNVmGiQJxXHm1ZT888dHmAnmYOksBLkChGUYA==`

Hex: `00000000049A430B7721A3559868902715C79B5653F3CF1D1E60279983A4B012E40A119460`

Hash: `AAAAAASeclRQJiE6vfoIjp8HxTZRaqMxMGMORZqrdSmOAUuFfA==`

Hex: `00000000049E72545026213ABDFA088E9F07C536516AA33130630E459AAB75298E014B857C`

More:

`AAAAAAQh51mzdpW5w+/+yK46nezAbMp5xn3XGMRxNBu7wTSWHQ==`
`AAAAAAT8KI/Xub72swAm0CPT/1DoS9jig4IyfK6ZnvU+8VGaXg==`
`AAAAAATYILi+qpLlRt3UACCDwHM5y3kvZhma+za0VmYDjkyRTQ==`
`AAAAAAQLXlq1CHz1kLFiJ2LKER3y/D2E6ktH8tUva6XzmLfonQ==`

Comment: 296 bits is an exceptionally odd length for a hash.  Are you sure it actually is one?

Comment: I have not checked closely but these look like [Microsoft Security Identifiers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962011.aspx). SID normally have a specific string representation, but they really are binary objects that can be, as such, encoded in Base64.

Comment: Well, it is not a hash. A hash would be uniformly distributed. No leading zeroes like that. As Thomas suggests, these are probably IDs or surrogate keys of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a hash. You always have a base64 encoded data (the one that ends with '==') and the hex value of the decoded data.

I am not sure what type of data this is, but I am almost sure that it is binary data.

```
AAAAAATOM2KIII+kbR/Dqw3TLTw4PHsGPZft2c+b93rImFIuAQ== 
    0000000004CE336288208FA46D1FC3AB0DD32D3C383C7B063D97EDD9CF9BF77AC898522E01
AAAAAASaQwt3IaNVmGiQJxXHm1ZT888dHmAnmYOksBLkChGUYA== 
    00000000049A430B7721A3559868902715C79B5653F3CF1D1E60279983A4B012E40A119460
AAAAAASeclRQJiE6vfoIjp8HxTZRaqMxMGMORZqrdSmOAUuFfA== 
    00000000049E72545026213ABDFA088E9F07C536516AA33130630E459AAB75298E014B857C
AAAAAAQh51mzdpW5w+/+yK46nezAbMp5xn3XGMRxNBu7wTSWHQ== 
    000000000421E759B37695B9C3EFFEC8AE3A9DECC06CCA79C67DD718C471341BBBC134961D
AAAAAAT8KI/Xub72swAm0CPT/1DoS9jig4IyfK6ZnvU+8VGaXg== 
    0000000004FC288FD7B9BEF6B30026D023D3FF50E84BD8E28382327CAE999EF53EF1519A5E
AAAAAATYILi+qpLlRt3UACCDwHM5y3kvZhma+za0VmYDjkyRTQ== 
    0000000004D820B8BEAA92E546DDD4002083C07339CB792F66199AFB36B45666038E4C914D
AAAAAAQLXlq1CHz1kLFiJ2LKER3y/D2E6ktH8tUva6XzmLfonQ== 
    00000000040B5E5AB5087CF590B1622762CA111DF2FC3D84EA4B47F2D52F6BA5F398B7E89D
```